# jquery: (newbie) trying to get a tooltip to work

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am using the example code from here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/kyBwU/

But since I don't want the user to decide where the arrow comes from - I am setting the arrow myself to a certain position.
Since I am not using a textbox, I want the tool tip to display as it mouses over an image with the class name "hide-option"

My modified code:

```
   <script>
    $(function() {

        var position = { my: 'left center', at: 'right+10 center' };


        position.collision = 'none';

        $('.hide-option').tooltip('option', 'position', position);
        $('.hide-option').tooltip('option', 'tooltipClass', className);
        $('.hide-option').tooltip();
    });




  </script>
```

my html:

```
<img src="siteImgs/comments_icon.png" class="hide-option" title="Total comments: 80" >
```

But it does not work, it just gives me the error in the console:
"Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option' "

Since I am a newbie, I have no idea where exactly I went wrong... can you help me to get this to work **and** tell me where I went wrong please?

The CSS is the same as the one on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the example `$('input[type="text"]').tooltip();` is called before setting options.

you should do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/y9r4ho45/1/):

```
    $('.hide-option').tooltip();
    $('.hide-option').tooltip('option', 'position', position);
    $('.hide-option').tooltip('option', 'tooltipClass', className);
```

Comment: Can you write out the full functions text please? I'll copy it and try it because right now I'm confused...

Comment: ok, I moved those three outside the main function, and I am getting a tooltip (but its a weird long tooltip (not like the one in the demo, I am getting a big gray bar) and it gives me this error in the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined